# Custom date only filter kendo grid jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was trying to implement a filter by date only alongside the default operators provided by the kendo-UI grid header filter.
But I keep getting this error message in the console :

[image]

```js
var sampleData = [{
  EventID: 1,
  EventName: "Event 1",
  EventDateTime: new Date(2013, 8, 10, 17, 0)
}, {
  EventID: 2,
  EventName: "Event 2",
  EventDateTime: new Date(2013, 8, 10, 18, 0)
}, {
  EventID: 3,
  EventName: "Event 3",
  EventDateTime: new Date(2013, 8, 10, 19, 0)
}, {
  EventID: 4,
  EventName: "Event 4",
  EventDateTime: new Date(2013, 8, 10, 20, 0)
}, {
  EventID: 5,
  EventName: "Event 5",
  EventDateTime: new Date(2013, 8, 11, 19, 0)
}, {
  EventID: 6,
  EventName: "Event 6",
  EventDateTime: new Date()
}, ];

$(function() {
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: function(e) {
        e.success(sampleData);
      }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
      parse: function(data) {
        var events = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var event = data[i];
          event.EventDate = kendo.toString(event.EventDateTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
          events.push(event);
        }
        return events;
      },
      model: {
        id: "EventID",
        fields: {
          EventID: {
            editable: false,
            nullable: true
          },
          EventName: {
            validation: {
              required: true
            }
          },
          EventDateTime: {
            type: "date"
          },
          EventDate: {
            type: "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    filterable: {
      extra: false,
      operators: {
        //Overriding the default list of operators displayed in the filter menu
        string: {
          startswith: "Starts with",
          endswith: "Ends with",
          eq: "Is equal to",
          neq: "Is not equal to",
          isnullorempty: "Is empty",
          isnotnullorempty: "Is not empty",
          contains: "Contains",
          doesnotcontain: "Does not contain"
        },
        date: {
          ed: "Is equal date only",
          eq: "Is equal to",
          neq: "Is not equal to",
          gte: "Is after or equal to",
          gt: "Is after",
          lte: "Is before or equal to",
          lt: "Is before",
          isnullorempty: "Is empty",
          isnotnullorempty: "Is not empty"
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "EventName",
        title: "Event Name"
      },
      {
        field: "EventDate",
        title: "Event Date",
        template: "#= kendo.toString(EventDateTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm') #"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.511/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

This is a dojo code sample of the current behavior: https://dojo.telerik.com/aheMIbID

Comment: Thank you for including the dojo link to a working example, but please always include the code within the question itself so that people do not need to go off-site to understand the context of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while built-in operators like "eq" are known to Kendo (eq is defined here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.data.js#L1163 ), your custom operator "ed" is not.

You need to either monkey-patch `Query.filterExpr` or follow the tutorial you've been following, https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/filter-by-date, more closely.